# Is the addSource onChange callback of Mediator LiveData executed on the main thread by default?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

From the documentation:

> **addSource (LiveData source, 
>                   Observer onChanged)**
>
> Starts to listen the given source LiveData, onChanged observer will be
>   called when source value was changed.
>
> onChanged callback will be called only when this MediatorLiveData is
>   active.
>
> If the given LiveData is already added as a source but with a
>   different Observer, IllegalArgumentException will be thrown.

From the source code, it says that the addSource function is always executed on the main thread.

```
@MainThread
public <S> void addSource(@NonNull LiveData<S> source, @NonNull Observer<? super S> onChanged) ...
```

Does this mean that the callback provided to the addSource method also runs on the main thread?

I would like to understand this because I want to do a `setValue` inside the callback and `setValue` needs to be run on the main thread.

I want do something like:

```
viewState.addSource(someLiveData) { networkResourceResult ->
    viewState.value = currentViewState().copy(showLoadingSpinner = networkResource.status)
}
```

So will this be a safe thing to do?

Comment: From my experience it is executed on main thread.

Comment: Looking at the source code it seems `Observer`'s `onChanged` is called from the Main thread only. Hence it is safe to call `setValue`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `postValue()` method to set values from worker thread

> You must call the `setValue(T)` method to update the `LiveData` object from the main thread. If the code is executed in a worker thread, you can use the `postValue(T)` method instead to update the `LiveData` object.

Look through [Update LiveData objects](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#update_livedata_objects) paragraph